# example OAuth 1.0 implementation in java

Tags: java, rest, oauth, access-token, signature

I need an example in java to be able to consume an API using OAuth 1.0 to generate the token :
NB: i have only those informations (the consumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccesToken and the acessTokenSecret).
I have searched int the internet but I have not found a result that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same but, actually, I have an example provided by the admins of the API that I'm trying to consume.
Since no one replied to this thread, I'll paste the mentioned example here, hoping it could help in some way.
Also, if someone can give me a hand, understand the code and explain how to implement it, it would be great.

```java
package com.example.entities;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.oauth.client.OAuthClientFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.HMAC_SHA1;
import com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthParameters;
import com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSecrets;

public class SSRestServiceClient {

    /*
    * private constructor to avoid construction of object.
    */
    
    private SSRestServiceClient(String url, String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, int timeoutSeconds) {

        OAuthParameters params = new OAuthParameters().signatureMethod(HMAC_SHA1.NAME).consumerKey(consumerKey).version(OAUTH_VERSION);
        OAuthSecrets secrets = new OAuthSecrets().consumerSecret(consumerSecret);
        Client httpClient = Client.create();
        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(timeoutSeconds * 1000);
        httpClient.setReadTimeout(timeoutSeconds * 1000);
        OAuthClientFilter filter = new OAuthClientFilter(httpClient.getProviders(), params, secrets);
        httpClient.addFilter(filter);
        httpClient.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
        this.consumerKey = consumerKey;
        this.webResource = httpClient.resource(url);
    }
    
    /*
    * Creates instance of the Client class, returns existing instance if it's already created.
    */
    
    public static synchronized SSRestServiceClient getInstance(String url, String consumerKey, String consumerSecret) {
    return getInstance(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, 0);

    }   
    
      /*  
       * Creates instance of the Client class, returns existing instance if it's already created.
       */
    
    public static synchronized SSRestServiceClient getInstance(String url, String consumerKey,String consumerSecret, int timeoutSeconds) {
         if (client == null || client.getConsumerKey() == null || !client.getConsumerKey().equals(consumerKey)) {
             if (timeoutSeconds != 0 && timeoutSeconds < ONE_MINUTE) {
                 timeoutSeconds = ONE_MINUTE;
             }
             client = new SSRestServiceClient(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, timeoutSeconds);
         }
         return client;
    }
    
    /*
     * Return a list of all active source cities.
     */
    
    @Override
    
    public CityList getAllSources() {
        return webResource.path(GET_ALL_SOURCES).get(CityList.class);
    }
}
```